# How to convert a list of paragraphs in a dataframe based on symbol?

Tags: r

I have a a vector of text containing multiple paragraphs separated by four stars :

```
 text <-("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus metus sapien
 ****
 maximus id commodo vitae, imperdiet sed ante. Nunc tristique velit quis est ultrices, faucibus. 
 ****
 Curabitur sit amet orci nulla. Mauris sed interdum diam, et suscipit nisi.
 ****
 Integer eu arcu eu tortor molestie mollis ut vitae erat. Integer justo tortor
 ****
 facilisis non condimentum in, tincidunt nec erat. Mauris vel dictum elit.")
```

I Want to convert my vector into a dataframe based on the four stars separators :

```
 |text                                                                                         |
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus metus sapien                  |
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
 |maximus id commodo vitae, imperdiet sed ante. Nunc tristique velit quis est ultrices, faucibus.|
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
 |Curabitur sit amet orci nulla. Mauris sed interdum diam, et suscipit nisi.                     |
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
 |Integer eu arcu eu tortor molestie mollis ut vitae erat. Integer justo tortor                  |
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
 |facilisis non condimentum in, tincidunt nec erat. Mauris vel dictum elit.                      | 
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` :

```
data.frame(text = strsplit(text, '\\*{4}\n\\s')[[1]])

#                                                                                                text
#1                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus metus sapien\n 
#2 maximus id commodo vitae, imperdiet sed ante. Nunc tristique velit quis est ultrices, faucibus. \n 
#3                       Curabitur sit amet orci nulla. Mauris sed interdum diam, et suscipit nisi.\n 
#4                    Integer eu arcu eu tortor molestie mollis ut vitae erat. Integer justo tortor\n 
#5                           facilisis non condimentum in, tincidunt nec erat. Mauris vel dictum elit.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fixed = TRUE`

```
data.frame(text = strsplit(text, "****\n ", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])
                                                                                                 #text
#1                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus metus sapien\n 
#2 maximus id commodo vitae, imperdiet sed ante. Nunc tristique velit quis est ultrices, faucibus. \n 
#3                       Curabitur sit amet orci nulla. Mauris sed interdum diam, et suscipit nisi.\n 
#4                    Integer eu arcu eu tortor molestie mollis ut vitae erat. Integer justo tortor\n 
#5                           facilisis non condimentum in, tincidunt nec erat. Mauris vel dictum elit.
```